# Font Assets not loaded on mobile

Tags: wordpress, fonts, webfonts, google-fonts, wordpress-block-theme

I am using several locally hosted fonts on my website. However, when I open the page on a mobile phone (or *chrome dev tools with a "mid-tier" or lower mobile setting*), some of the fonts are not loaded anymore.

More specifically, they are not displayed on the initial page load. As soon as I do a soft reload, the fonts are displayed as expected.

The website can be visited [here](https://maiball-heidelberg.de).

I currently think that the fonts are not laoded due to their size. The Google Fonts causing the issues are "Noto Serif Display" and "Ballet". Noto Serif Display is over 100KB large and smaller fonts load without issue, that's why I assume the size is the problem.

I already converted them to woff2 to save space, but the problem persists. I can also not rule out that the cause is something else, because I cannot recall having this issue a few days ago.

The website is made using a custom WordPress Theme and the fonts are imported via the theme.json file.

Any hints or ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Everything loads fine in my end.  `--wp--preset--font-family--noto-serif-display: Noto Serif Display;`. Also on mobile just to confirm.

Comment: Have you tried it in the dev tools while setting it to mobile?

Comment: Hi @Daniel. The fonts are loading without any issues, also in the dev tools in Chrome browser. Have you tried checking this behavior from another device? This issue is most often caused by the cache functionality. Please clear your WordPress and your browser Cache, and check if the changes are visible to you.

Comment: Thank you, the issue seems to be resolved.